# Android. Espresso. How to check that text is shown in a specific language without hard code strings?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I need to check my fragment when I change the app language.
Here is my Android Espresso test:

```
 @Test
    public void changeLanguages() {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        String[] appLanguages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.app_lang_codes);
        for (int index = 0; index < appLanguages.length; index++) {
            String currentLang = appLanguages[index];
            Locale currentLocale = new Locale(currentLang);
            if (currentLocale.equals(AppLanguageService.getLocaleRO(context))) {
                // click Romanian
                onView(withId(R.id.containerLanguageRO)).perform(click());

                onView(withId(R.id.textViewSelectLanguage)).check(matches(withText("Selecți limba")));
            } else if (currentLocale.equals(AppLanguageService.getLocaleEN(context))) {
                // click English
                onView(withId(R.id.containerLanguageEN)).perform(click());

                onView(withId(R.id.textViewSelectLanguage)).check(matches(withText("Select language")));
            } 
        }
    }
```

Ant it's working fine. OK!

But as you can see I need to hard code the string for a specific language for the test.
"**Selecți limba**" and "**Select language**". And I think it's not good.

Is it possible to not use hard code strings to check that text is shown in a specific language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  mActivityRule.getActivity()
```

to get the activity you are testing. With this you could fetch a string from your resources like this:

```
mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.your_string)
```

You could rewrite your check like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textViewSelectLanguage)).check(matches(withText(mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.your_string))));
```

where `your_string` is the name of your string resource in your strings.xml files.

Comment: I meant another. If in strings.xml in one language I has text not in correct language. How I can check this? Only by hard code text (as in my example)?

Comment: you mean if you have your strings.xml files wrong in your application? I guess that you can only check by a second - independent - set of strings that you use to compare it. either hardcoded in the tests or you create strings.xml files in your test environment and use those.